# Cannot use query selector with id's that includes "."

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-selectors, selector

Assume that I have a `<li id="gen__1002_____46.14_li">`

I want to select this `li`.

To be able to achieve it, I wrote,

```
var id="gen__1002_____46.14_li";
document.querySelector("#" + id);
```

But querySelector returns as;

```
Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element': '#gen__1002_____46.14' is not a valid selector.
```

When `id` does not include `dot` character, it selects correctly.

My question is, how can I select a html dom elements where its id includes `.` char. Is there any restriction that id cannot include `.` char.

Is there any solution for me rather than removing .'s in ids.

Comment: Try like `$('#gen__1002_____46\\.14_li');`

Comment: I have already tried it, But this returns as; Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element': '#gen__1002_____46\\.14' is not a valid selector.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the dot

```
$('#thisIs\\.anId') // will select <span id="thisIs.anId">test</span>
```

And in pure js:

```
var id="gen__1002_____46.14_li";
id = id.replace(/\./g, '\\\\.'); // escaping dots using regex
document.querySelector("#" + id);
```

**EDIT**

If you just want to select element by id, use `getElementById()`

```
document.getElementById(id);
```

Comment: I have already tried it, But this returns as; `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element': '#gen__1002_____46\\.14' is not a valid selector.`

Comment: @mmu36478 what browser are you using ?

Comment: @mmu36478 check the updated answer

Comment: If you're using `document.getElementById`, you do not need a hash :)

Comment: @Terry, sorry, my mistake...thanks for pointing out