# Selecting a node with a dot or fullstop in the name with Puppeteer

Tags: css-selectors, puppeteer

We've a form with a lot of elements in it like this, with the only unique identifier being the name attribute which is always of the form company.something

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="company.name" value="">
```

Both of the following attempts at selecting this text input fail

```
await page_c.click('input[name=company.name]')
await page_c.type('input[name=company.name]', client.companyName)

await page_c.click('input[name=company\.name]')
await page_c.type('input[name=company\.name]', client.companyName)
```

with the following error

```
Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'input[name=company.name]' is not a valid selector.
```

Is there a way to handle elements where the name attribute had a dot or full stop in it with out rewriting the front end please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is in an attribute selector, you don't need to settle for double escaping — quoting the attribute value is the less error-prone solution:

```
await page_c.click('input[name="company.name"]')
await page_c.type('input[name="company.name"]', client.companyName)
```

Answer (score 3):

After searching for the error message I found [Cannot use query selector with id's that includes "."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46399023/cannot-use-query-selector-with-ids-that-includes) double escaping works.

```
await page_c.click('input[name=company\\.name]')
await page_c.type('input[name=company\\.name]', client.companyName)
```